# Checking if an array is sorted

Tags: java, array, sorting, comparative-review

I've come up with two ways to check to see if array is sorted and return true if it is.

```
public static boolean checkSortedness(int[] data)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        if(data[i-1] > data[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've also seen the `i` start at 0 and compare the next element instead of the previous. The other way which involves another variable is

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] data)
{
     int previous = data[0];
     for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
     {
         if(previous > data[i])
             return false;
         previous = data[i];
     }
     return true;
}
```

Which way is better and are there any alternatives?

What should the array parameter be named? I call it `data` but I've  considered `arr`. This class is meant to be fairly generic.

Comment: Arent you missing a Point that array can be sorted in assending as well descending orders. your program only takes care about Arrays sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The better way would be your first, as you're just comparing the element A with element B and not creating a copy of the element as you are in the second version.

Additionally, to be a bit of a pedant - you don't want to name a function `checkSortedness` where its only returning a boolean, over `isSorted` where its assumed it would return a boolean.

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] data){
    for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i-1] > data[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Three other answers, and none have picked up on the bug yet, so, here's the bug, in the second version:

The input array `new int[]{4}` is sorted, right? The first method will return true. The second method will return true, fine... but, what about the array `new int[]{}` (the empty array)? The first method will return true. The second method will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

The two methods are not the same. The second is buggy.

To me, this makes the first method the clear winner.

Now, while you are reading this, also note that in Java, the `{` brace should, by convention, be at the end of a line, not on a new line. What you have in your code is C* style coding (C, C++, C#, etc.).

Also, use `final` when appropriate....

Your code should look like:

```
public static final boolean checkSortedness(final int[] data) {
    for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i-1] > data[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The name 'data' is the best given the two options, as 'arr' is just making it sound like a pirate. We already know it is an array by the type.

I prefer the first code, for all the same reasons jsanc623 said.

In case you wanted a very generic version:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isSorted(T[] data) {
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i - 1].compareTo(data[i]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use this code along with the version you have, and make other versions for the other primitive types as needed.

> I've also seen the i start at 0 and compare the next element instead of the previous.

The reason why it is best to start at 1, is that it is always clear there is an element before, otherwise you have to make your terminating condition be one less - not as elegant.

Adding a Comparator version:

```
public static <T> boolean isSorted(T[] data, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (comparator.compare(data[i - 1], data[i]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which will allow an ordering to be better controlled.

Comment: Good call on the type generic version

Comment: The generic version is ... nice, but, will not actually work for the OP's int[] array. Additionally, it would be best to take a Comparator argument. Still, I like this answer too.

Comment: Added the comparator version.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an element in Java is \$O(1)\$.
Both methods do \$O(n)\$ comparisons   (n = number of  elements).
The fist one has \$O(2n)\$ accesses, the second one only \$O(n)\$, but you store a extra variable.

I would prefer the first one, cause storing costs often more time.

By the way, why don't you just sort them, using [int[]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort)?

Sorting an already sorted array often costs (depending on the implementation) also \$O(n)\$. The implementation of the standard Java array-sort is documented [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html).

I think if you want to sort the array if it is not sorted just use this sorting method.

References: [accessing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615908/array-access-complexity).

Comment: I can't find any useful implementation details about Java array sort at the link you posted. Only that some sort implementation will be called which isn't shownin the code.

Comment: You can't use big O analysis in such a way to analyse actual performance of the code (e.g. iterating through a linked list may be O(N) just as much as iterating through an array list but by Knuth will the performance differ in practice). As a matter of fact after the JIT has done the obvious optimizations the performance difference between the two methods will be pretty much indistinguishable - one certainly won't do twice the memory accesses.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of doing the arithmetic comparison on every other array element, so that you can shave the number of iterations by half?

```
public static final boolean isAscending( final int[] data ) {
    if ( data == null || data.length < 2 ) {
        return data != null;
    }
    int secondPrevious = data[0];
    int i;
    for ( i = 2 ; i < data.length ; i += 2 ) {
        if ( data[i - 1] < secondPrevious || data[i] < data[i - 1] ) {
            return false;
        }
        secondPrevious = data[i];
    }
    // edit:
    // return i == data.length ? data[i - 1] > secondPrevious : true;
    return i != data.length || data[i - 1] > secondPrevious;
}
```

First, I use @Shree's advice to rename the method, so that it is known that the comparison is done in an ascending order. Second, the initial `if` statement takes care of a `null` argument or single-element array to return a result immediately. Third, at the final `return` statement, we take care to compare the last element with the second-last element in case that was skipped during the `for`-loop, else we know that we have compared all elements and can `return true`.

Based on my simple microbenchmarks, halving the number of iterations at the expense of two comparisons in the `if` statement pays off once you have more than 15 elements thereabouts...

Comment: This appears to be a form of loop unrolling. Are you sure its any faster? It seems like something the optimizer would do anyways if it new the values inside the array weren't going to change.

Comment: Right, it is a form of loop unrolling. I've stopped short of looking at the compiled output/the generated code though. I should do that to verify this point, thanks for the suggestion.