# Is this the best way to check sorting (in recursion) without loops?

Tags: c#, array, recursion, sorting

Please let me know if there is a shorter way to  do it again without any kind of loops. Recursion only.

```
static bool isSortedArray (int[] ar, int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
        return true;
    bool temp = isSortedArray(ar, length - 1);
    if (temp && ar[length - 1] <= ar[length])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an array is sorted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58533/checking-if-an-array-is-sorted)

Comment: Nope, because it's with only recursion...

Comment: What language is this? Please add a language tag.

Comment: Strange I'v added them O_o anyway fixed...

Comment: Is this Java or C#?  It can't be both.

Comment: People, please read the post before commenting including the title!
@m0nhawk

Comment: It is c# indeed.

Comment: If you called isSortedArray in the if condition itself, and had `ar[length - 1] <= ar[length]` as the 1st condition, isSortedArray(ar, length - 1) as 2nd, you can take advantage of short circuiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the naming guidelines methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing.

---

If you evaluate two conditions connected by `&&` you should always evaluate the faster one first. You can return the result of the condition directly.

This can be reached if you forget the `temp` variable and rearange the condition like

```
static bool isSortedArray (int[] ar, int length)
{
    if (length == 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return ar[length - 1] <= ar[length] && isSortedArray(ar, length - 1);
}
```

---

You should also take care of the posibility that `ar` will be null or that the number of elements is smaller than `length`.

---

Using braces `{}` for single `if..else` statements will make your code less error prone.

---

`ar` as a parametername is not well choosen. You shouldn't shorten parameter names.

`isSortedArray` should be better named `IsArraySorted`.

---

A construct like

```
if (condition)  
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    // more code here
}
```

will always make the `else` redundant because if the condition is true it will never be reached.